# Error creating bean with name 'armeriaServer' defined in com.linecorp.armeria.spring.ArmeriaAutoConfiguration

Tags: java, spring-boot, zipkin

as I wanted to install a zipkin server I got this error message.

I just followed the quickstart of the zipkin website.

Here is the exception code:

```
    2021-06-21 11:49:10.858  WARN [/] 43208 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'armeriaServer' defined in com.linecorp.armeria.spring.ArmeriaAutoConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.linecorp.armeria.server.Server]: Factory method 'armeriaServer' threw exception; nested exception is java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Armeria server failed to start
    2021-06-21 11:49:10.867  INFO [/] 43208 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-06-21 11:49:10.897 ERROR [/] 43208 --- [           main] o.s.b.SpringApplication                  : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'armeriaServer' defined in com.linecorp.armeria.spring.ArmeriaAutoConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.linecorp.armeria.server.Server]: Factory method 'armeriaServer' threw exception; nested exception is java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Armeria server failed to start
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
```

Thank you for helping,

Kind regards

Comment: Try to close all javaw instance from taskmanager. It should solve your problem.

Comment: I did this, but it doesn't work either. I also didn't saw a javaw in the tm, therefore I just closed all java tasks

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. That was due to incomplete installation in my case. I had zipkin already downloaded and ran `$ curl -sSL https://zipkin.io/quickstart.sh | bash -s` again but I stopped it in between.

Just deleting all the files and re downloading again solved my problem.

To download:

```
$ curl -sSL https://zipkin.io/quickstart.sh | bash -s
```

Run the jar now:

```
$ java -jar zipkin.jar
```

Another possible reasons:

1. If you have zipkin-dependencies jar installed, make sure both zipkin jar and zipkin-dependencies jar are of same version.
2. If you are trying to store traces in elastic search and getting this error:

   then in elasticsearch.yml (ELASTICSEARCH_HOME > config > elasticsearch.yml), add this line `action.auto_create_index: .monitoring*,.watches,.triggered_watches,.watcher-history*,.ml*` this basically allows zipkin to create indices automatically in elasticsearch.